# Swap layout buttons in LTR / RTL devices

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am working on RTL and LTR layouts in my Android project.

I've got two buttons - one on left, one on right. What I need is -

if user is using RTL they should stay as they are
if user is using LTR they should swap - left go to right, right go to left

How to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Header -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/top_header"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/left_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/right_button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Body -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this one out http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot.